# Гормон счастья стоит ли кавычить?

Tags: кавычки

«Серотонин – гормон счастья». Кавычить ли тут что-нибудь?

Answer (score 1):

***Серотонин – гормон счастья***

Если  это название статьи, то кавычки ставить не нужно.  Пример: https://www.drliberanskaya.ru/serotonin/

В кавычки  желательно заключить  сочетание в тексте, где есть глагол «называют», например:

*Серотонин – это химическое вещество, которое имеет широкий спектр функций в организме человека. Его иногда называют «гормоном хорошего настроения» и **«гормоном счастья»**.*